# Can't find variable addproduct error in while using redux in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have the following code inside flatlist for adding product into cart using redux

```js
<View style={styles.priceContainer}>
  <Text style={styles.gridItemTitle}>${item.price}</Text>
  <Button size="small" onPress={()=> addproduct(item)} style={styles.addBtn} accessoryLeft={PlusIcon} />
</View>
```

and this is how i am using map Dispatch to props in the bottom of functional component

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        products: state.groceryReducer.productList
    }
}
    
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addproduct: (product) => dispatch(addToCart(product))
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Products)
```

but it is showing an `error can't find variable addproduct` 
can you tell why i am getting this error or what i am doing wrong any solution or suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems likely your issue is that there is no addproduct function available to execute. You haven't given us enough code to know if its a naming issue or an import issue but both could be to blame.

Comment: [i am using this as reference] https://github.com/cheetahcoding/React-Native-Tutorials/blob/redux_tutorial/src/foodForm.js I just follow this @Deadron

Comment: See here, they imported action `addFood` [here](https://github.com/cheetahcoding/React-Native-Tutorials/blob/redux_tutorial/src/foodForm.js#L11), where you're importing `addproduct` action?

Comment: i have also imported this `import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addToCart } from '../store/actions/grocery';` @Deadron

Comment: Thanks @Deadron  for your suggestions i got my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using class component you should find use `this.props`:

```
<View style={styles.priceContainer}>
  <Text style={styles.gridItemTitle}>${item.price}</Text>
  <Button size="small" onPress={()=> this.props.addproduct(item)} style={styles.addBtn} accessoryLeft={PlusIcon} />
</View>
```

if you are using a functional component you have to pass the props an the argument of function like this:

```
const ProductPage(props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.priceContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.gridItemTitle}>${item.price}</Text>
      <Button size="small" onPress={()=> props.addproduct(item)} style={styles.addBtn} accessoryLeft={PlusIcon} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

or just pass just the function from the props like this:

```
const ProductPage({addproduct}) => {

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahdi i got it what i was doing wrong it works